# Continuity of a complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I have to show that the complex function is continous using ϵ and  δ: $ f(z) = |z+2i| $

My attempt:

Assume that $ |z - z_0| < δ $ is true.
I also assume that  δ = ϵ. I have to proof the following inequality:
$$ |f(z) - f(z_0)| < ϵ $$
$ |f(z) - f(z_0)| $ = $| |z+2i|-|z_0+2i|| $ <= $ |(z+2i) - (z_0+2i)| $ = $ |(z-z_0) + (2i-2i)| $ = $|z-z_0+0|$ < $δ$ = ϵ □

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computations are correct, but you express yourself in an unappropriate way. The starting point must be “Let $\varepsilon>0$”. Then you choose $\delta=\varepsilon$. What you want to prove next is that$$|z-z_0|<\delta(=\varepsilon)\Longrightarrow\bigl||z+2i|-|z_0+2i|\bigr|<\varepsilon\text.$$But\begin{align*}\bigl||z+2i|-|z_0+2i|\bigr|&\leqslant\bigl|(z+2i)-(z_0+2i)\bigr|\\&=|z-z_0|\\&<\delta\\&=\varepsilon\text.\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, appriciate!